# Cannot select an option immediately after updating options

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I want to dynamically manage the number of options under a select tag, and automatically select the last added option after updating the options.
Here is what I tried :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" 
            src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular.min.js" 
            data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedOption">
      <option value="">-----Select an option-----</option>
      <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.value}}">
        {{option.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
    <button ng-click="addOption()">Add option</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

When you add an option, the select switch to a non existant value. It seems like the select value update is resolved before the options update.

Does anyone have any idea on how i could fix that ?

Comment: Could you provide a Plunker (http://plnkr.co) or a working demonstration that we can look at?

Comment: Interesting! OP had a plnkr script: http://plnkr.co/edit/VhltCOZOYOtFW0WewKfQ?p=preview, which appears to have been deleted in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state: I want to dynamically manage the number of options under a select tag, and automatically select the last added option after updating the options.

You can do this by changing your HTML like so (EDITed after comment):

```
<option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.value}}" ng-selected="option.value==options.length-1"> {{option.name}}</option>
```

More information on the [ng-selected directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSelected)

Line 19 in your accompanying js should also be deleted - this line currently reads like so:

```
    $scope.selectedOption = $scope.options.length - 1;
```

Comment: it seems that "ng-selected" is expecting a boolean and not an index. But otherwise this was exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much !